# Disable perks Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, cheats

Is there a way to *remove* activated perks in skyrim? I know the console command to add them, but I just want to rearrange my skill points without becoming overpowered. I unlocked some stupid perks that I never use or will use and I don't want to do 38 levels again, to solve it the fair way. Anyone knows a solution? 
Thanks

Answer (score 4):

The console command is:

```
player.removeperk <perkid>
```

You'll need to know the perk ID for whichever perk it is you want to remove.  The UESP pages for [each skill tree](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Skills) list the perk ID's, but there's also a good script down at the bottom of [this page](http://chrizel.github.com/skyrim/) which, if run, will remove *all* perks.  However, looking at the file in a text editor will show you an itemized list of all the perks and their ID's.

Comment: I'm pretty sure not all perks are removed "cleanly" (Think Bloody Mess from Fallout 3), and sometimes you will need to save/reload or restart the games for some changes to take effect.

Comment: @kotekzot, I didn't run into that problem myself, but perhaps I didn't remove a problematic perk.  It wouldn't surprise me if there were unintended consequences, however.  +1 for the cautionary tale.

Answer (score 2):

As of Patch 1.9, when your skill hits level 100, you can make it legendary and recover all the points.  This is described in detail in this (my) answer:  https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/376086/174247

That said, additionally, if you have the Dragonborn Add On or, (more likely) you're playing the Legendary edition which includes that (and is the only edition available on Switch, XBox One, and PS4), then there is another answer.

During the final quest of that expansion, you gain the capability to rewrite all of your perks.  Specifically:

> At the conclusion of [At the Summit of Apocrypha](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/At_the_Summit_of_Apocrypha#Conclusion) after the Dragonborn has killed Mirak, Hermaeus Mora grants the Dragonborn the ability to reset any skill perk purchases at the cost of 1 dragon soul per 'reset'.  The details are found at the link.